# Intellij IDEA, build artifact using Ant?

Tags: ant, intellij-idea, tomcat6

I might be missing something, but I have been struggling with this problem for some time now.

I have an Web application with Ant build script. I would like to set up an Artifact to this module, (which is the .war file, generated using ant), so that I could deploy this war file, to the configured Tomcat server.

But I am not able to figure out, how to make Intellij use my Ant script to build artifact. I see an option to Run Ant Targets, but this just runs the Ant target and Intellij then proceeds to generate Artifact, in the usual way.

Please let me know if the question is ambiguous. The problem is not Ant Integration with Intellij. I could just use the Ant window and run any target and also could make an Ant target run as part of Build. The problem is to associate an Artifact to a module and leverage the Ant script to build that artifact. I need this to enable, tight tomcat integration, Since while integrating the Tomcat server, I can specify an artifact to be deployed.

Note: Intellij IDEA version 11.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDEA can either deploy Artifact or the **External Source** (directory or file) that is built by Ant or any other tool:

[image: External Source]

It's not possible to associate IDEA Artifact with Ant build.

Comment: Thank you. I have come to the same conclusion too. I am marking this question answered, so that others do not have to run around in circles...

Comment: You can, however, make the Ant build task a prerequisite to the Run Configuration by setting it at the bottom of the Run/Debug Configurations window (not pictured above).